# Will calling functions inside function wrapped by tf.function be slower than inlining the function?

Tags: tensorflow

Will it cause performance degradation if I organize my codes by having extra functions in graph mode?

E.g.

```
def repeated_assign(vars,value):
    for var in vars:
        var.assign(value)

@tf.function
def train_step(model,x,y):
    ...
    repeated_assign(vars,value)
    ...

#v.s.

@tf.function
def train_step(model,x,y):
    ...
    for var in vars:
        var.assign(value) #inlining the function
    ...
```

in cases that train_step is called many many times and there are considerable amounts of small function calls inside train_step. Or is it better to inline all of those small function calls?

Comment: Since there are small functions inside the train function, inlining all small functions with `tf.function` won`t provide much speedup.If there is a big function with many expensive operations inside the train function, it will help speedup the performance if we inline the big function. Thanks!